# How to automate the tracking of ratios and other values for a set of stocks or ETFs?

Tags: stocks, investing, etf, online-tools, online-data-source

I'm interested in monitoring a set of financial products (say ETFs WLOG) continually (but not continuously).

My current plan is the following. Say I want to survey the top ten Large Cap Growth Equities ETFs at http://etfdb.com/etfdb-category/large-cap-growth-equities/. Moreover, I want to supervise their Price-Earning ratio, Price-Book Ratio, Beta and other variables delineated at http://www.forbes.com/sites/johndobosz/2013/09/25/10-ratios-to-make-you-money-in-stocks/.

I'd then create an Excel spreadsheet with the ticker symbols and a column for each variable. Afterwards, whenever I want to update information, I'd research each stock individually and then edit my spreadsheet, research the next stock and edit my spreadsheet for that stock, ...

How could I do this much more productively and with less time? Xtf.com's premium version may tender this, but its gratis version doesn't and I'd be grateful for free assistance:

[image: Screen shot showing a set of investments and the values being tracked]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spreadsheets need not be static, they can pull data from the web. 
[This articl](http://tracenotes.com/tools/ptracker.html)e describes the method you seek.